# Installing colortbl package

Tags: packages, miktex

I have MiKTeX 2.9 basic installation (using Windows). When I go into the package manager and try to install `colortbl` package (to get `colortbl.sty`) I get the following message:

> Error response from server: 404

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably the server is down. Try changing the server from the 'Repository' menu.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Package installed successfully

Answer (score 10):

MiKTeX Package Manager is synchronized with the last used 'Package Repository'.

Your error occurs when the last used one is a CTAN mirror, which is currently down.

To overcome this, choose a different mirror through the command 'Change Package Repository' from the 'Repository' menu, as shown in the following image:

[image]

After a MiKTeX update, it is also recommended to run the 'Synchronize' command from the same menu, otherwise you lose the synchronization between your installed MiKTeX distribution and the latest one available on CTAN.

Comment: Just hitting `Synchronize` worked for me.