# MiKTeX savesym package not found

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

Using MiKTeX 2.9 package manager (`mpm.exe`) I try to install `savesym.sty`. It is listed in the mpm window, I can right click it and choose 'Install'. But when mpm tries to install it aborts with a "not found" error:

> ```
> package repository: http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
> lightweight database digest: b412617853dd68b9a7087203775787c7
> going to download 1311 bytes
> going to install 2 file(s) (1 package(s))
> downloading http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/savesym.cab...
> ```

And then a dialog pops up simply saying

> Error response from server: 404

Following that link to the repository, the file does indeed not seem to exist. So how can I solve this problem?

And it is not an administrator rights problem. I can install and use other packages using mpm.

Comment: have you tried with another repository?

Comment: Worked just fine with the berlin repository.

Comment: Change Package Repository as @Federico as per in karlkoeller's answer at [Installing colortbl package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118411/15717) and as a last resort if it's only savesym.sty package then save the [savesym.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/savesym/savesym.sty) in your working folder.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ I see there is `savesym` archived as `savesym.tar.lzma`, but according to your log file the (older) CAB version was requested. For the reason I can only guess, that this mirror was not up to date some days ago (it is now).

So some general hints:

- You can check whether your selected mirror is (officially) up to date on [MiKTeX Package Repositories](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories).
- On each update a file `mpm.ini` is updated first. This can also be found in archive `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma` on each mirror. For `savesym` you can among other entries read there:

  ```
  [savesym]
  Type=TarLzma
  ```

  So, if you’d get this error message again, you could check, if there would be a inconsistency.